# External SWF loads, but does not display

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

So this is similar to a problem I had a few days ago, but not quite the same. If I try to load an external SWF, it loads all right, but I can't see anything! There are buttons in this external SWF, and I can click the buttons and they work, so the SWF is there and functional, I just can't see any of it (the screen is completely white). Also if I click the button, IT appears (with the active frame of its animation) but nothing else does. The audio also plays on its cue. Everything seems to work except that it's invisible.

This is the relevant code:

```
private var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
private var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../lib/Introduction.swf");
private var introdummy:Sprite;
```

(different method)

```
introdummy = new Sprite();
addChild(introdummy);
myLoader.load(url);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, introLoaded); 

function introLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
     introdummy.addChild(myLoader.content);  
}
```

Comment: Everything works, audio plays, but it's invisible?! You can click buttons, but they are invisible?!

Comment: Yep. The buttons are there, but I can't see them. No clue why. :/

Comment: try the ProLoader Class instead of the Loader. Also, are both swf compiled with same version?

Comment: ProLoader did the same thing. Versions are different though: the main SWF is version 10 and the external SWF is version 20.

Comment: that'll be the problem then i reccon. why would you load a "newer" swf into an ancient one? Compile the Main swf with the latest version and see what happens. obviously it would be best to be up to date on both, since your still in development stage.

Comment: Yeah, that was because I was using an old version of FlashDevelop that defaulted to using an old FlashPlayer. Only problem...I updated the main one to 20 and the same thing happened! This is getting ridiculous.

Comment: It's ridiculous that **the buttons are there but you can't see them**.. How the hell you know they are there?!

Comment: The code you are showing is suspicious, First the variables are private which implies they are member variables but then the rest of the code has no modifier and look like a code used in a timeline frame.

Comment: Popov-I know they're there because I can click on them, and when I do, THEN they appear because of the keyframe on the button. Botmaster-The part with the private variables is in the top of the class where I declare/initialize all of the variables used in the class. The rest of the code (other than the event listener) is inside a function designed to load up the SWF.

Comment: Here's an update: I have since found out that all the stuff concerning the "introdummy" object and the "introLoader" event method is completely pointless. When I removed all code relating to these two things, the SWF loaded exactly the same. It's still invisible though.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you all are going to laugh your butts off when you see what was wrong...

My main SWF has a white background. My external SWF has a black background, and all the text on it was white. When I imported the SWF in, the background showed the main SWF's background. So all the text showed as white on a white background, so it was invisible. :/

Answer (score 0):

add your swf file like this:

```
introdummy.addChild(myLoader);
```